# Smallest number added to FLT_MAX to cause overflow

Tags: c

I need to find number which is a power of 2 that when added to FLT_MAX will cause overflow. However, when I printf very large power, like 2^300, inf still doesn't appear. Also, I thought that as FLT_MAX is the maximum floating point represented, adding 1 to it will cause overflow immediately.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(){
    float f = FLT_MAX;
    printf("%f", f + pow(2,300));
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: But 2^300 is not infinity. Why did you expect that result? What did you actually get? Have you tried checking the floating point environment for exceptions?

Comment: @Useless “2^300 is not infinity” is such a strange thing to say when `0x1.0p300f` actually is infinity, and when the title is about the smallest number to add to `FLT_MAX` to produce infinity—which surely is finite, I mean `FLT_MAX` took us nearly all the way to infinity, it shouldn't take infinity to reach it. Don't get me wrong, there exist `float` values to which you need to add infinity to reach infinity, but you shouldn't expect that property from `FLT_MAX`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is `(FLT_MAX - nextafterf(FLT_MAX, 0))/2`, that is, exactly 0x1p+103 or approximately 1.014120480e+31.

There is a mistake in the method you use to determine the answer : the standard function `pow` returns a `double`, and [C's “usual arithmetic conversions” (C11 6.3.1.8:1)](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8p1) mean that the expression `f + pow(2,300)` is computed as a `double`. It is then printed as a `double` because of how arguments are passed to variadic functions.

[This C program](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/KokVcj) shows how you can arrive to the `float` value that, added to `FLT_MAX` with `float` addition, results in `float` infinity:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    float f = FLT_MAX;
    printf("FLT_MAX: %a\n", f);
    float b = nextafterf(f, 0);
    printf("number before FLT_MAX: %a\n", b);
    float d = f - b;
    printf("difference: %a\n", d);
    printf("FLT_MAX + d: %a\n", f + d);
    printf("FLT_MAX + d/2: %a\n", f + d/2);
    printf("FLT_MAX + nextafterf(d/2,0): %a\n", f + nextafterf(d/2,0));
    float answer = d/2;
    printf("answer: %a %.9e\n", answer, answer);
}
```

It prints:

```
FLT_MAX: 0x1.fffffep+127
number before FLT_MAX: 0x1.fffffcp+127
difference: 0x1p+104
FLT_MAX + d: inf
FLT_MAX + d/2: inf
FLT_MAX + nextafterf(d/2,0): 0x1.fffffep+127
answer: 0x1p+103 1.014120480e+31
```

It shows that if you take the difference between `FLT_MAX` and its lower neighbor (call this difference `d`), as you could expect, `d` added to `FLT_MAX` produces `inf`. But this is not the smallest `float` you can add to `FLT_MAX` to produce `inf`—there are smaller candidates. It is enough to add exactly half of `d` to `FLT_MAX` in order for the result to tound up to `inf`. If you add less than that, on the other hand, the result is rounded down to `FLT_MAX`.

Comment: The `printf("%f", f + pow(2,300));` is working with `double` not `float`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm coming to that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found the answer which is 2^103 now.

Comment: @jordan.goe Do not hesitate to take advantage of C's hexadecimal notation for floating-point values. `2^103` is written `0x1.0p103`, and if you want to emphasize that it's a `float`, you can write `0x1.0p103f`.

Answer (score 0):

This line is working with `double` not `float`.

```
printf("%f", f + pow(2,300));
```

To be working with `float` you need

```
printf("%f", f + powf(2,300));
```

and in this case the output is

```
inf
```

In the second case the `float` result is promoted to `double` in the call to `printf`, but it's too late, the value is already in an overflow representation.

Answer (score 0):

```
//float=(-1) ^ s * 2 ^ (x - 127) * (1 + n * 2 ^ -23)    
//                                              s xxxxxxxx nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
//FLT_MAX       3.402823466e+38F    2 ^ 128     0 11111110 11111111111111111111111
//FLT_MIN       1.175494351e-38F    2 ^ -126    0 00000001 00000000000000000000000
//FLT_TRUE_MIN  1.401298464e-45F    2 ^ -149    0 00000000 00000000000000000000001
//ONE           1f                  2 ^ 0       0 01111111 00000000000000000000000
//INFINITY      -                   2 ^ 128+    0 11111111 00000000000000000000000


 union
 {
     float f; 
     int i;
 }k,k2,k3;


 k.i  = 0b01111111011111111111111111111111; //  2^128  FLT_MAX
 k2.i = 0b01110011000000000000000000000000; //  2^103
 k3.f = k.f + k2.f;                         //  2^128+ INFINITY
```